# How avoid MySQL dead lock in transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, transactions

I've two tables where I storage two rows per table with id's and name. I need lock parallel without dead lock.

For example:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
THREAD 1                                 | THREAD 2
start transaction;                       | start transaction;
select * from t1 where id = 1 for update | select * from t2 where id = 1 for update
select * from t2 where id = 1 for update | select * from t1 where id = 1 for update
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Imagine that the lines are executed in ABSOLUTELY in the same sequence in TWO different threads. How to solve this problem?

Comment: you say you don't want a deadlock; what *do* you want to happen with the above?

Comment: can you sort your two ids and always lock the lower one first?